# Storing Hex values into std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, vector, hex

I'm trying to store a bunch of hex values into a vector so I can convert them and process them. I have a *.dat file witch looks like that:

> 0002 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
>
> 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002 0004 0003
>
> 0004 0001 fffe fffa fffd fffa 0000 0000
>
> ....

I'm reading the file with this code:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;

std::ifstream file;
file.open("/home/vktrbhm/SciVis/DATA/elev0/L0e000a.dat", std::ios::binary);
if(file.is_open()){
    std::cout << "hello data"<< std::endl;
}else{
    std::cerr << "Na ahh aahhhaaaa .... Wrong Directory"<< std::endl;
}

// get length
file.seekg(0, file.end);
int length = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);

data.resize(length);

file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
file.read((char*)&data.front(), length);
file.close();

std::cout << data.at(0) << std::endl;
```

But my output is just � and not the value. I know I have to convert this at one point but I don't know how.

I would appreciate some help and sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: what do you mean , is your dat file text or binary. If you do `cat x.dat` what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
std::cout << data.at(0) << std::endl;
```

Is going to print a character, using the character encoding native to your environment. Most likely, this will result in `data.at(0)` having the character `'\0'` printed out on screen, which doesn't correspond to a character glyph in most (probably all) encodings. If you want it to print a number, you need to cast it.

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(data.at(0)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Ah ok. So my data vector is storing all the hex values and to convert them I need to use static_cast. That helped a lot. Thanks